# JQuery load/ajax Only Reading From Static HTML File

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-type

My current Javascript code looks like:

```
$('.app-link').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax($(this).attr('href'), {
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $( "#app-content" ).html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This works perfectly when the 'href' is a static html file such as "content-lite.html," but when it's not, something like "ajax.do?command=LoadApp&app=1&cache=3193.716273197833&lite=true," it only loads a couple of lines. The output from both of those URLs is identical; if I load the ajax.do link directly, I get the desired output.

I've checked the encoding(text/html)/content-type(UTF-8) on my servlet and it looks perfect.
Now, the output is large (7,000 lines). Could this be causing the problem? I'm trying to test this on IE8.

Comment: Please clarify `ajax.do?command=LoadApp&app=1&cache=3193.716273197833&lite=true` ? Thanks

Comment: It's a link on my site that produces html output for Ajax commands.

Comment: Please illuminate. `js` ? If possible, can post output of commands ? Thanks